# WPF MVVM - trouble moving things to the view model

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am starting my way with MVVM..
I already implemented a window and need to change it to be mvvm
but.. in my window i have a function that searches the visual tree
how can i do this in my view model? i cannot access a function in the view from viewmodel..

Comment: *What* are you searching the visual tree for ? If you can answer the why - you can modify your design to MVVM. MVVM relies primarily on ViewModels data-binding (vs hacking up the view). The backing view model should be exposing whatever it is you are searching for as a property that can be bound to.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom interface that exposes that function and inject its implementation in your ViewModel.

It might not be the most elegant solution, but it is a quick one, (mock-)testable and loosely-coupled.

Please refer to this answer for a well-written example:

[How to play Sound and Animations in MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954511/how-to-play-sound-and-animations-in-mvvm)

Comment: +1 Another good example for this is an interface for adding/removing parts to/from view or for saving its layout - create an interface with theses methods, implement in code-behind of view, then when view-model and view are created, inject view into view-model using that interface.

Answer (score 0):

You don't do that in your ViewModel. Accessing the View should be done in the View and if that requires code an option would be to develop a control that contains the code and use the control in the View.

Do not add any knowledge about the View to the ViewModel. That would mess up the pattern and remove (some of) the benefits of MVVM.

Comment: right now my view has a button that when pressed does a certain calculation and is supposed to put the value calculated in any control that is a textbox. for this i search the visual tree for all controls of type textbox and go over this collection and set the value

Comment: how can i implement this using mvvm?

Comment: The way to implement this scenario is by making a ViewModel with a property for each value that is in the View. Add a Command to the ViewModel that recalculates all values. Bind the textboxes of the View to the Value properties of the ViewModel.

Comment: To make the View dynamic: add a collection of Values to the ViewModel. Add a command to the ViewModel that adds a new value to the collection. In the View create a similar collection of textboxes (e.g. by adding a ListBox with an ItemTemplate that shows a TextBox for each item in the collection) and bind the ListBox to the Collection of values on the ViewModel.